# Intersection of 2 lines - numerical analysis

Tags: c#, arrays, numeric, intersection

I have 2 two-dimensional arrays that represent 2 lines/curves, something like:

```
(y1,t1) (y2,t2) ... (yN, tN)
```

and

```
(Y1, t1) (Y2, t2) ... (YN, tN)
```

My goal is to find the last point from the beginning of the array just before the intersection of 2 lines/curves.

I tried comparing

```
if ( (y1 > Y1 && y2 < Y2) || (y1 < Y1 && y2 > Y2) || (y1 == Y2) )
```

in order t0 find intersection but it does not work or verifying result is very difficult due to large number of points.

Is there nay elegant solution in C#  using open source numerical analysis library that all I need to do is feed the 2 arrays into the function and get intersection?

Comment: Are they lines or curves (i.e., are the points in a set colinear).  By they way, showing the points in something like this as (Yn, Tn) is a bit unusual. Normally, it would be (Tn, Yn) (since time would be shown on the _"x-axis"_

Comment: Note that asking for a library is off-topic, as is asking for an "elegant" solution, without defining, objectively, what "elegant" means.

Comment: Heretic Monkey - I guess you did not read the question to the end - the definition of "elegant" follows right away: "feed the 2 arrays into the function and get intersection"

Answer (score 1):

On c# your algorithm looks like:

```
public void FindFirstIntersection(int[,] curve1, int[,] curve2)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < curve1.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            var curve1Point = curve1[i, 0];
            var curve2Point = curve2[i, 0];

            var curve1NextPoint = curve1[i + 1, 0];
            var curve2NextPoint = curve2[i + 1, 0];

            if (curve1Point > curve2Point && curve1NextPoint < curve2NextPoint ||
                curve1Point < curve2Point && curve1NextPoint > curve2NextPoint ||
                curve1Point == curve2Point)
            {
                //Do smth
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is correct, but I was looking for a numerical analysis library to simply call a function passing 2 arrays to it.